# PowerShell, download a file if the filename has changed?

Tags: powershell, download, invoke-webrequest

I've been reading the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533819/how-can-i-download-a-file-only-if-it-has-changed-using-powershell) on downloading files under certain conditions, and everything there is clear, but I have a bit of a problem with the place I am trying to download from.

I would like to download from the button beside `.zip` in the bottom left that reads `64 bit` (i.e. this would be the 64-bit .zip portable version of the app). https://code.visualstudio.com/download# . I would like to:

- Find the name of the file that would be downloaded, so that I can compare it to what I already have, then
- Download the file if has a different name.

The problems are that a) I can't see the filename, and b) if I right-click the link and select Copy Link, that is not a downloadable object.

I am trying to do this in PowerShell.

Comment: Are you looking to download the portable or msi?

Comment: Exactly, the portable `.zip` package (you put it into portable mode by then creating a folder called `data` inside).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As a one-time step, use your web browser to interactively find the URL that is used to request the download, such as via the `Network` tab of Google Chrome's / Brave's Developer Tools view, which in this case leads to:

  - `https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=win32-x64-archive`
  - Fortunately, this URL itself does *not* include a specific version number, but only abstractly requests the *latest stable* download, which means that you can use this URL to *programmatically*, given that it (likely) won't change.
- Then use [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) with `-Method Head` to only download the response *header*, without actually downloading the file yet.

  - You can extract the download file name - which includes the version name, e.g. `VSCode-win32-x64-1.72.2.zip` - from the header and then decide whether a download is required.
  - If so, repeat the `Invoke-WebRequest` call with (implied) `-Method Get`, and pass the file name to `-OutputFile`

Note: Both [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) and the underlying .NET APIs have changed between *Windows PowerShell* (versions up to v5.1) and *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, so two distinct solutions are presented below:

***Windows PowerShell* solution**:

```bash
$hd = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Method Head 'https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=win32-x64-archive'

# Extract the file name from the response.
$downloadFileName = $hd.BaseResponse.ResponseUri.Segments[-1]
```

***PowerShell (Core) 7+* solution**:

```bash
$hd = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Head 'https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=win32-x64-archive'

# Extract the file name from the response.
$downloadFileName = $hd.BaseResponse.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Segments[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I am now able to automate my VS Code downloads now. If a new version is detected (with your code), my script renames old version folder, then fetches the new version, then extracts it into my chosen location, then fetches the `data` folder from the previous version to retain my settings.